# Python's Statsmodels glm throws PerfectSeparationError, R returns results

Tags: python, r, statsmodels, glm

I am trying to port some prototype R code into Python, and I'm having issues mapping from stats::glm in R. The first test set returns reasonable looking values in R, but fails out in python.

The Python code:

```
import numpy
import pandas
from statsmodels.formula.api import glm
from statsmodels.api import families
from statsmodels.genmod.families.links import logit

my_data = pandas.DataFrame({
    'success': [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1],
    'col_a': [5000.0, 10000.0, 11000, 20000.0, 20000.0, 25000.0, 30000.0, 30000.0, 40000.0, 41000.0],
    'col_b': ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', None, 'b', 'c', 'c', None, 'd'],
    'col_c': [5487.0, 5654, numpy.NaN, 2918.0, 912.0, numpy.NaN, 1236.0, 234.0, 2390.0, 21092.0],
})
formula = 'success ~ col_a + col_b + col_c'

result = glm(formula, family=families.Binomial(link=logit), data=my_data, missing='drop').fit()

# Throws statsmodels.tools.sm_exceptions.PerfectSeparationError:
#    Perfect separation detected, results not available
```

The R code

```
library(stats)
my_data = data.frame(
    success=c(1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1),
    col_a=c(5000.0, 10000.0, 11000.0, 20000.0, 20000.0, 25000.0, 30000.0, 30000.0, 40000.0, 41000.0),
    col_b=c('a', 'a', 'b', 'b', NA, 'b', 'c', 'c', NA, 'd'),
    col_c=c(5487.0, 5654.0, NA, 2918, 912.0, NA, 1236.0, 234.0, 2390.0, 21092.0)
)
myFormula <- stats::formula(paste0("success ~ col_a + col_b + col_c"))
fit <- stats::glm(myFormula, data=my_data, family=stats::binomial(link="logit"), na.action=stats::na.exclude) 
summary(fit)

Call:
stats::glm(formula = myFormula, family = stats::binomial(link = "logit"), 
    data = my_data, na.action = stats::na.exclude)

Deviance Residuals: 
 [1]  0  0     0        0  0     0

Coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
(Intercept)  7.370e+01  1.026e+06       0        1
col_a       -9.826e-03  3.757e+01       0        1
col_bb       1.474e+02  7.500e+05       0        1
col_bc       2.457e+02  1.334e+06       0        1
col_bd       3.538e+02  2.943e+06       0        1
col_c        3.282e-12  1.849e+02       0        1

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 5.4067e+00  on 5  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 2.5720e-10  on 0  degrees of freedom
  (4 observations deleted due to missingness)
AIC: 12

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 23
```

In reading other StackOverflow posts, the typical issue is a success variable with only one value, or a single predictor which perfectly captures the success variable. However, at least by human inspection that isn't present here (and R doesn't indicate it). I'm wondering if there's some hidden defaults which differ between Python and R, but a cursory analysis hasn't found any.

Comment: Note that all your variables have a p-value of 1. Even if you could get this output in Python, the model wouldn't be useful. `stats::glm` in R just doesn't check for separation and will give you a "maximum likelihood" estimate even when your likelihood function really has no maximum.

Comment: The R values are not reasonable whatsoever. Your model residuals are all 0. That  `stats::glm` doesn't fail outright does not mean the model is at all reasonable. A cursory glance at the summary shows this